# User input is appended multiple times

Tags: python, list, append

I want to store a user input in a list, based on the length of which the program will take a decision afterwards.

As it is currently, the user input is store multiple times each turn the user gives an input but it should only appended once.

```
moves = int(input("Enter the number of moves: "))

throw00 = []
throw01 = []
throw10 = []
throw11 = []

player_move_dif = [] #create an empty list out of your for-loop

for i, turn in enumerate(range(moves)): #use enumerate() to count the loops
    if i >= 0: #first move has no previous one
        player_move_dif.append(input("Choose your move number %s (0 or 1):" % (turn+1)))
        player_move_2 = int(player_move_dif[i])
        player_previous_move = int(player_move_dif[i-1])
    else:
        player_move_dif.append(input("Choose your move number %s (0 or 1):" % (turn+1)))
        player_move_2 = int(player_move_dif[i])
        player_previous_move = int(player_move_dif[i-1])
        #continue
       
    for turn in range(moves): #store player moves in the respective lists    
        if player_move_2 == 0 and player_previous_move == 0:
            throw00.append(player_move_2)
        elif player_move_2 == 0 and player_previous_move == 1:
            throw01.append(player_move_2)
        elif player_move_2 == 1 and player_previous_move == 0:
            throw10.append(player_move_2)
        else:
            throw11.append(player_move_2)
```

So after 5 turns the list (here `throw11`) is size 25 instead of 5.

[image]

I tried `extend` instead of `append` but that gave me a TypeError instead.

Comment: "player_move_2" and "player_previous_move" are only changed before the inner for-loop. Maybe you don't want an inner for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

**This Will Work, Because Here Is The Error**

```py
moves = int(input("Enter the number of moves: "))

throw00 = []
throw01 = []
throw10 = []
throw11 = []

player_move_dif = [] #create an empty list out of your for-loop

for i, turn in enumerate(range(moves)): #use enumerate() to count the loops
    if i >= 0: #first move has no previous one
        player_move_dif.append(input("Choose your move number %s (0 or 1):" % (turn+1)))
        player_move_2 = int(player_move_dif[i])
        player_previous_move = int(player_move_dif[i-1])
    else:
        player_move_dif.append(input("Choose your move number %s (0 or 1):" % (turn+1)))
        player_move_2 = int(player_move_dif[i])
        player_previous_move = int(player_move_dif[i-1])
        #continue
        
    #############################################################################
    """REMOVED THIS LINE OF CODE- for turn in range(moves): #store player moves in the respective lists  Because This Means That The Number Of Moves The Player Entered `append` the given input that number of times"""
    ################################################################################

    if player_move_2 == 0 and player_previous_move == 0:
        throw00.append(player_move_2)
    elif player_move_2 == 0 and player_previous_move == 1:
        throw01.append(player_move_2)
    else:
        throw11.append(player_move_2)



print(throw00)
print(throw01)
print(throw10)
print(throw11)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
moves = int(input("Enter the number of moves: "))

throw00 = []
throw01 = []
throw10 = []
throw11 = []

player_move_dif = [] #create an empty list out of your for-loop

for i, turn in enumerate(range(moves)): #use enumerate() to count the loops
    print(i,turn,'\n')
    if i >= 0: #first move has no previous one
        player_move_dif.append(input("Choose your move number %s (0 or 1):" % (turn+1)))
        player_move_2 = int(player_move_dif[i])
        player_previous_move = int(player_move_dif[i-1])
    else:
        player_move_dif.append(input("Choose your move number %s (0 or 1):" % (turn+1)))
        player_move_2 = int(player_move_dif[i])
        player_previous_move = int(player_move_dif[i-1])
        #continue
       
    if player_move_2 == 0 and player_previous_move == 0:
        throw00.append(player_move_2)
    elif player_move_2 == 0 and player_previous_move == 1:
        throw01.append(player_move_2)
    elif player_move_2 == 1 and player_previous_move == 0:
        throw10.append(player_move_2)
    else:
        throw11.append(player_move_2)
```

I've just removed the inner for loop from your code.

```
for turn in range(moves): #store player moves in the respective lists
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing way too much work and have a lot more problems than a nested loop.

The line that allows the player to choose 0 or 1 was moved to the top of the loop and outside of any conditions (where it belongs). I removed the unnecessary `enumerate`, all unnecessary conditions, wordy var names, and the unnecessary nested `for` loop. The final conditions were all replaced with a `dict`.

```
moves = int(input("Enter the number of moves: "))

throw = {
    '00':[],
    '01':[],
    '10':[],
    '11':[]
}

move_diff = []

for i in range(moves): #enumerate is entirely unnecessary
    move_diff.append(input(f'Choose your move number {i+1} (0 or 1):'))
    
    if i >= 0:
        pm  = int(move_diff[i])
        ppm = int(move_diff[i-1])

        #conditions aren't necessary if you simply concoct a key
        throw[f'{pm}{ppm}'].append(pm) 
        
#I chose 4 moves and 1 on every move      
print(throw) #{'00': [], '01': [], '10': [], '11': [1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

**homework**

1. make sure the user enters at least 2 moves and handle if less
2. handle if the user does not enter 1 or 0
3. create a game loop for the entire overall game